# The vue.js implementation of event handling in Fullcalendar is not working and I am not understanding why

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, fullcalendar, vuex

I tried to follow a video on YouTube to set up the event interaction component and I typed it exactly. I am using VSCode and it keeps giving me a typeError when I add the $ symbol to `this.store.commit` under the 
`handleSelect`. It won't add the event at all, but if I put the $ symbol first then remove after clicking the calendar it adds the event(s) to the calendar and it is infuriating. If you can help me, I would greatly appreciate it. I already tried googling it for similar scenarios and found nothing, I checked the comments section of the video and there was nothing helpful their either, and I even went to the fullcalendar website and nothing was helpful. Now, I am not ruling out the possibility that I might have overlooked something, so if you can direct to me somewhere that might be of use that would be useful too.

**Agenda.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <Fullcalendar 
            :plugins="calendarPlugins" 
            :header="{
                left: 'prev today next', 
                center: 'title', 
                right: 'dayGridMonth, timeGridWeek, timeGridDay, listWeek'
            }"

            :buttonText="{
                today: 'Today',
                month: 'Month',
                week: 'Week',
                day : 'Day',
                list: 'List'
            }"

            :weekends="true"
            :selectable="true"
            :events="EVENTS"
            @select="handleSelect"
        />

        <!-- <modals-container/> -->
    </div>
</template>

<script>
require('@fullcalendar/core/main.min.css')
require('@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.min.css')
require('@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.min.css')
require('@fullcalendar/list/main.min.css')

import Fullcalendar from '@fullcalendar/vue'
import DayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import TimeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid'
import InteractionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction'
import ListPlugin from '@fullcalendar/list'

import { mapGetters } from "vuex"

export default {
    data: () => ({
        calendarPlugins: [
            DayGridPlugin,
            TimeGridPlugin,
            InteractionPlugin,
            ListPlugin
        ]
    }),
    components: {Fullcalendar},
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters(["EVENTS"])
    },
     methods: {
         handleSelect(arg){
             console.log(arg)
             this.$store.commit("ADD_EVENT", {
                id: (new Date()).getTime(),
                title: 'Event',
                start: arg.start,
                end: arg.end,
                allDay: arg.allDay
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**store.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        events: []
    },
    getters: {
        EVENTS: state => state.events
    },
    mutations: {
        ADD_EVENT: (state, event) => {
            state.events.push(event)
        }
    },
    actions: {}
})

export default store;

**main.js**
```

import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import store from './store/store'

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
    render: h => h(App),
    store
}).$mount('#app');

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Agenda/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Agenda from './components/Agenda.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Agenda
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

**STACKTRACE:**

```
[Vue warn]: Error in beforeUpdate hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'calendar' of undefined"

found in

---> <Fullcalendar>
       <Agenda> at src/components/Agenda.vue
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>
warn @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619
```

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 TypeError: Cannot read property 'calendar' of undefined
    at DayGridSlicer.Slicer._sliceDateSpan (main.esm.js?1b0d:8519)
    at DayGridSlicer.eval [as sliceDateSelection] (main.esm.js?1b0d:1552)
    at DayGridSlicer.Slicer.sliceProps (main.esm.js?1b0d:8446)
    at SimpleDayGrid.render (main.esm.js?379b:1542)
    at SimpleDayGrid.Component.receiveProps (main.esm.js?1b0d:3951)
    at DayGridView.render (main.esm.js?379b:1597)
    at DayGridView.Component.receiveProps (main.esm.js?1b0d:3951)
    at CalendarComponent.renderView (main.esm.js?1b0d:6298)
    at CalendarComponent.render (main.esm.js?1b0d:6162)
    at CalendarComponent.Component.receiveProps (main.esm.js?1b0d:3951)
```

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'calendar' of undefined
    at DayGrid.updateSize (main.esm.js?379b:914)
    at DayGridView.AbstractDayGridView.updateSize (main.esm.js?379b:1429)
    at CalendarComponent.updateSize (main.esm.js?1b0d:6311)
    at Calendar.updateSize (main.esm.js?1b0d:7157)
    at Calendar.windowResize (main.esm.js?1b0d:7150)
    at later (main.esm.js?1b0d:1016)
```

Comment: Show the error with stacktrace

Comment: Okay, I updated the the question with the errors along with the stack trace

Comment: to access the store, you need to do this.$store.somethod

Comment: I should update that. It doesn't throw the error if I remove $, but when I add it throws the errors. If I remove $ for the ```$store.method``` it works, but it won't add new events to the calendar yet I can click. When I add it and try clicking, and adding events it throws errors and the calendar grid disappears. Another weird thing is that if I then remove $ from $store.commit() as the server is running it posts the event

Comment: I  finally got a response on my comment that I put under the video that I was following and got a response. He says he fixed it once he deleted the ```:buttonText="{}" plugin for the calendar